# Multiple calls to canvas.putImageData in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, setinterval, putimagedata

I'm building an application that makes a user-specified number of calls to `canvas.putImageData` in Javascript. Between each call to `putImageData`, the image data is modified. The time needed to modify the data varies between calls. The user also needs to be able to stop the animation while it's running (I'm using a button). Initially I used:

```
for (var i=0; i < n; i++) {
    canvas.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);
    modify(imgdata);
}
```

However, this doesn't display each frame, only the last one. What does work is to put an alert after `canvas.putImageData`, but that's super annoying. I tried using `setInterval` and `cancelInterval` as I'm sure many would suggest, but this doesn't work for me for two reasons:

- The time needed to modify the image data varies.
- setInterval is asynchronous; if the delay I use is too short, calls to modify(imgdata) pile up on the stack and users won't be able to stop the animation when they want.

How can I make this work correctly?

Comment: Your resize method is amazing !! However when looking at the code i saw that you could be quite faster with little efforts : cache width, height, and more important, the data in every method instead of using them in the core loops ( var imgData = img.data ; ). cache also repeating computations (4*...) . You might also use performance arrays of 32 or 64 bits in some cases, stackEnd  being one example. ( i talked a little about this here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14429346/856501 ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a repeating setTimeout():

```
var shouldStop = false;

function iteration() {
  canvas.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
  modify(imgData);

  if (!shouldStop) {
    window.setTimeout(iteration, 1000);
  }
}

function stop() {
  shouldStop = true;
}
```

This will display and modify the image data each second.

Another solution would be to delegate the modify algorithm to a web worker.

Comment: Excellent! This worked perfectly! Thanks so much! Here's the application now in case it helps anyone:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/178840674/seamCarve.html
upload an image, then for "Edit Mode:" select Resize Mode -> Optimal; then click anywhere on the image or edit the textboxes to see the animation. Use the "Cancel" button to stop the animation.