# HTML5 canvas disable antialias on primitive (curves, ...)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

How can I disable the antialias effect in the following code ? I'm using Chrome 29.

**[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xnwrg/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById( 'test' );
var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

// These lines don't change anything
context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true );
context.closePath();

context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fill( );
```

Comment: this question makes me think of this one, which i answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424648/nice-ellipse-on-a-canvas/14429346#14429346   In a few words : with a quite big performance hit, you can post-process the draw or re-implement the primitives without antialiasing (quite some work maybe), but there's no way to get it done as fast without antialiasing.

Comment: When I was making a graphing script, I found if you draw same thing 20 times, the anti-aliased pixels stack up to become aliased. The faster way is to draw the desired shapes on an image buffer, clamp the alpha (0% or 100%) by reading the data, and draw the image buffer into the canvas. (I don't have time to write the code)

Comment: Please also see my "retro canvas" project here: https://github.com/epistemex/retro-context-canvas (it's free)

Comment: That link is now https://github.com/epistemex/8-bit (and there's also this one: https://github.com/mohayonao/gretro)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `imageSmoothingEnabled`only affects *images* drawn to canvas using `drawImage()` (hence the name **image**SmoothingEnabled). There is sadly no way to disable this for lines and shapes.

As with 6502's answer and previous answers on SO you will need to implement "low-level" methods to achieve this.

Here are some links to some common algorithms for various primitives:

- [Bresenham line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) ([see this answer for implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672279/bresenham-algorithm-in-javascript))
- [Midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) (and [ellipse with the same](http://www.hhhprogram.com/2013/05/draw-elipse-midpoint-elipse-algorithm.html)) [Here's an implementation](http://techforum4u.com/entry.php/816-How-To-Implement-Mid-Point-Circle-Drawing-Algorithm-In-C).
- [Bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) ([implementation at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25237/Bezier-Curves-Made-Simple))

The way you need to implement this is to get the x and y coordinates from these formulas. Then you need to either to use `rect(x, y, 1, 1)` or set a pixel directly by altering the image data buffer directly. The latter tend to be faster for these sort of things.

In both cases you will have a relatively huge performance reduction as you need to iterate using JavaScript versus browser's internal compiled iteration.

Comment: Re "reduction", What about OpenGL? Is the performance still penalized?

Comment: @Pacerier OpenGL is not relevant here.. did you mean WebGL? You could implement a solution in WebGL using shader.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no portable way to disable antialiasing when drawing on a canvas.

The only solution I found is reimplementing graphic primitives writing directly on the image data.