# Canvas getImageData() For optimal performance. To pull out all data or one at a time?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

I need to scan through every pixel in a canvas image and do some fiddling with the colors etc. For optimal performance, should I grab all the data in one go and work on it through the array? Or should I call each pixel as I work on it.

So basically...

```
data = context.getImageData(x, y, height, width);
```

VS

```
data = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1); //in a loop height*width times.
```

Comment: You could grab chunks and use web workers? That may be the best bet.  Or you could grab it all and give it to one worker to then distribute to other workers.  Kind of like communism.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like a good solution for large images. I'm working with 600x600 which isn't too bad but I was just wondering the best way to go about it and for curiosity sake which would be the optimal method least expensive way out of the 2.

Comment: In general, pull the whole pixel array at once.  This option "costs" 1 getImageData call and memory=600x600x4=1.44mb. But there may be more performant options depending on your project's needs.  Could you describe your project in more detail?

Comment: I'm essentially making a magic wand tool similar to photoshops. The stage I'm at is I've cut the item out of the background, and it needs some anti-aliasing/smoothing along the edges. I'm thinking to play with alpha values first before I mess with color sampling in relation to pixel neighbours. I've pulled all the data in one go and currently sending them row by row into a webworker for proocessing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll get much higher performances by grabbing the image all at once since :
a) a (contiguous) acces to an array is way faster than a function call.
b) especially when this function isa method of a DOM object having some overhead.
c) and there might be buffer refresh issues that might delay response (if canvas is
on sight... or not depending on double buffering implementation).

So go for a one-time grab.

I'll suggest you look into Javascript Typed Arrays to get the most of the 
imageData result.

If i may quote myself, look at how you can handle pixels fast in this old post of mine 
(look after 2) ):

### [Nice ellipse on a canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424648/nice-ellipse-on-a-canvas/14429346#14429346)

(i quoted the relevant part below : )

---

You can get a UInt32Array view on your ImageData with :

```
var myGetImageData = myTempCanvas.getImageData(0,0,sizeX, sizeY);
var sourceBuffer32     = new Uint32Array(myGetImageData.data.buffer);
```

then sourceBuffer32[i] contains Red, Green, Blue, and transparency packed into one unsigned 32 bit int. Compare it to 0 to know if pixel is non-black ( != (0,0,0,0) )

OR you can be more precise with a Uint8Array view :

```
var myGetImageData = myTempCanvas.getImageData(0,0,sizeX, sizeY);
var sourceBuffer8     = new Uint8Array(myGetImageData.data.buffer);
```

If you deal only with shades of grey, then R=G=B, so watch for

```
sourceBuffer8[4*i]>Threshold
```

and you can set the i-th pixel to black in one time using the UInt32Array view :

```
sourceBuffer32[i]=0xff000000;
```

set to any color/alpha with :

```
sourceBuffer32[i]= (A<<24) | (B<<16) | (G<<8) | R ;
```

or just to any color :

```
sourceBuffer32[i]= 0xff000000 | (B<<16) | (G<<8) | R ;
```

(be sure R is rounded).

---

Listening to @Ken's comment, yes endianness can be an issue when you start fighting with bits 32 at a time. 
Most computer are using little-endian, so RGBA becomes ABGR when dealing with them 32bits a once.
 Since it is the vast majority of systems, if dealing with 32bit integer assume this is the case,
and you can -for compatibility- reverse your computation before writing the 32 bits results on Big endian systems.
Let me share those two functions :

```
function isLittleEndian() {     
// from TooTallNate / endianness.js.   https://gist.github.com/TooTallNate/4750953
    var b = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var a = new Uint32Array(b);
    var c = new Uint8Array(b);
    a[0] = 0xdeadbeef;
    if (c[0] == 0xef) { isLittleEndian = function() {return true }; return true; }
    if (c[0] == 0xde) { isLittleEndian = function() {return false }; return false; }
    throw new Error('unknown endianness');
}


function reverseUint32 (uint32) {
    var s32 = new Uint32Array(4);
    var s8 = new Uint8Array(s32.buffer);
    var t32 = new Uint32Array(4);
    var t8 = new Uint8Array(t32.buffer);        
    reverseUint32 = function (x) {
        s32[0] = x;
        t8[0] = s8[3];
        t8[1] = s8[2];
        t8[2] = s8[1];
        t8[3] = s8[0];
        return t32[0];
    }
    return reverseUint32(uint32);
};
```

Comment: That looks very interesting. Thank you! I haven't worked with Typed Arrays before so I need to do some reading. Looks like it could be really useful for my project though! Cheers.

Comment: I'm sure it's just a typo but your `UInt32Array` should be `Uint32Array` (small I or JS will throw an error). Tip for OP: colors for Uint32 can also be given simply be using hex - no need to do shifting: `0xff00000` = black + alpha set to 255; for little-endian/LSB CPUs, opposite on big-endian/MSB CPUs. Byte-order is something you need to be aware of when dealing with low-level integer values (16/32 bits) as JS adopt Typed Arrays based on CPU architecture (mostly little-endian but there are big-endians out there..).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ken. I'm just reading up on bitwise operators and it's giving me a headache. @GameAlchemist - is || supposed to be single | in your last line of code?

Comment: why is `isLittleEndian` a function which is overwritten when it could be a boolean which is the result of a [immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)? won't this defeat the JIT?

Comment: i used a function because it's handy : you can put it anywhere in your code. For the JIT, functions are compiled only after many calls (20 for Chrome), i don't think it is hard to handle this case ( all this depends on the js engine of course )

Comment: Here's another way to do the 32 bit reversal with fewer memory writes: `(
     (x << 24)
     | ((x & 0xff00) << 8)
     | ((x & 0xff0000) >>> 8) 
     | (x >>> 24)
    );` You'll have to profile to see which is faster for your situation of course.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to what GameAlchemist said, if you want to get or set all the colors of a pixel simultaneously, but you don't want to check endianness, you can use a `DataView`:

```
var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var view = new DataView(data.data.buffer);

// Read or set pixel (x,y) as #RRGGBBAA (big endian)
view.getUint32(4 * (x + y*canvas.width));
view.setUint32(4 * (x + y*canvas.width), 0xRRGGBBAA);

// Read or set pixel (x,y) as #AABBGGRR (little endian)
view.getUint32(4 * (x + y*canvas.width), true);
view.setUint32(4 * (x + y*canvas.width), 0xAABBGGRR, true);

// Save changes
ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you're doing, but I'd suggest grabbing it all at once, and then looping through it.

Grabbing it all at once is faster than grabbing it pixel by pixel, since searching through an array is a lot faster than searching through a canvas, once for each pixel.

If you're really in need of speed, look into web workers. You can set each one to grab a specific section of the canvas, and since they can run simultaneously, they'll make much better use out of your CPU.

`getImageData()` isn't really slow enough for you to notice the difference if you were to grab it all at once or individually, in my experiences using the function.