# Canvas using Uint32Array: Wrong colors are being rendered

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 32-bit

I'm currently creating a JS canvas where I want to display a box of different colors.

I'm using uint32 for extra speed, and my colors never display correctly! 
I've looked at the examples mainly over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502117 where someone said in the comments:

> (small I or JS will throw an error). Tip for OP: colors for Uint32 can also be given simply be using hex - no need to do shifting: 0xff00000 = black + alpha set to 255; for little-endian/LSB CPUs, opposite on big-endian/MSB CPUs."

I'm certain my laptop is little-endian.

I have a demo of my issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/GhwUC/357/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canvasWidth  = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

var buf = new ArrayBuffer(imageData.data.length);
var buf8 = new Uint8ClampedArray(buf);
var data = new Uint32Array(buf);

for (var y = 0; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
        data[y * canvasWidth + x] = 0xff80d7ff // Should be light blue (#80d7ff)
    }
}

imageData.data.set(buf8);

ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

The color in question here is:

[image: color]

But the fiddle displays a yellow-ish color:
[image: color fail]

It's the same on other colors, thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:** thanks @Oriol for quick answer! I used the following function to  reverse my colors (in case anyone was interested):

```
function reverseUint32 (uint32) {
    var s32 = new Uint32Array(4);
    var s8 = new Uint8Array(s32.buffer);
    var t32 = new Uint32Array(4);
    var t8 = new Uint8Array(t32.buffer);        
    reverseUint32 = function (x) {
        s32[0] = x;
        t8[0] = s8[3];
        t8[1] = s8[2];
        t8[2] = s8[1];
        t8[3] = s8[0];
        return t32[0];
    }
    return reverseUint32(uint32);
};
```

Use it like: `reverseUint32(0xfc66feff)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens when you treat a Uint8Array buffer as a Uint32 in little endian:

```js
var buf = new Uint8Array([0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]).buffer;
console.log(new Uint32Array(buf)[0].toString(16));
// "78563412" in little endian, "12345678" in big endian
```

So in little endian, the order becomes AABBGGRR instead of AARRGGBB.

You could reverse `0x80d7ffff` to `0xffffd780`, but then it wouldn't work on big endian machines.

To avoid these problems you can use a `DataView`, which allows to specify the endianness, defaulting to big endian:

```
view.setUint32(offset, 0xffffd780, true);  // #80d7ff, in little endian
view.setUint32(offset, 0x80d7ffff, false); // #80d7ff, in big endian
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    canvasWidth  = canvas.width,
    canvasHeight = canvas.height,
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight),
    view = new DataView(imageData.data.buffer);
for (var y = 0; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
  for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
    var offset = 4 * (y * canvasWidth + x);
    view.setUint32(offset, 0x80d7ffff); // light blue (#80d7ff)
  }
}
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="256" width="256"></canvas>
```

But it seems that browsers haven't optimized much `DataView`, so it's slow. Then it might be better to set the color components separately in the `Uint8ClampedArray`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    canvasWidth  = canvas.width,
    canvasHeight = canvas.height,
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight),
    data = imageData.data;
for (var y = 0; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
  for (var x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
    var offset = 4 * (y * canvasWidth + x);
    // light blue (#80d7ff)
    data[offset+0] = 0x80; // red
    data[offset+1] = 0xd7; // green
    data[offset+2] = 0xff; // blue
    data[offset+3] = 0xff; // alpha
  }
}
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="256" width="256"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow I just figured it out right after you commented. Thanks!

Comment: Why is the order reversed?

Comment: Do you know if this is this influenced by endian-ness? i.e., if I run this code on a different endian orientation, will I need to supply the numbers as RRGGBBAA? That seems possible, given that that's the traditional order, and the suggested AABBGGRR here is a perfect reversal of byte order, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @apsillers Yes. It seems the proper way to avoid these problems is using a DataView.

Comment: Or you could just check for the endianness before hand, since I'm unsure dataView offers the same performance advantages as direct bitwise operation on 32bits Typed array. http://jsfiddle.net/andrewjbaker/Fnx2w/ by Paul Rouget. Ps: I sincerely don't know about performances impact, maybe it's just fine too.

Comment: @Kaiido Not sure. In the example of the question it might make sense to use a typed array because it assigns the same value to all pixels, so it could be reversed at the beginning if necessary. But if each pixel is different, and you may have to manually reverse each one depending on the endianness, then I don't think that a dataView performs much worse. But I don't know much about this.

Comment: Yep don't know either, but if I had to, I would definitely perform the endianness check only once at startup, defining my pixel manip function accordingly to the result. Unfortunately jsperf is down and I'm not curious enough to install it on my local.

Comment: Using (view) view.set???(i,val) has 3% the performance of (direct) `data[i] = val` Stats from FF. Direct writes per cycle : 23222 
View writes per cycle: 702 :  3.02% ....  View 1701 cycles * 10000 writes. Mean : 1424.832 (1e-6 sec).  direct 1701 cycles * 10000 writes. Mean : 43.063 (1e-6 sec)

Comment: @Blindman67 If the difference is that huge, I suspect it is a bug which should be fixed.

Comment: @Oriol It is not a bug, that is to be expected when calling a function (even native) Internal states must be pushed onto a stack, all values must be vetted, then it can do its thing, followed by reinstating internal state and returning to normal execution flow. Calling a function is always the slowest option.

Comment: @Blindman67 I know, but not that difference. It seems I can beat dataview performance with JS code. That should not happen. I will file a bug.

Comment: [This article from 2018](https://v8.dev/blog/dataview) explains that it was indeed a bug in v8. DataView performance should be on par with typed arrays nowadays :)

Answer (score 7):

### All about performance.

The best solution is to do an endian test.

```
var isLittleEndian = true;
(()=>{
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var buf8 = new Uint8ClampedArray(buf);
    var data = new Uint32Array(buf);
    data[0] = 0x0F000000;
    if(buf8[0] === 0x0f){
        isLittleEndian = false;
    }
})();
```

The write the pixels depending on the test.

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
var data = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);
var val = 0xffffd780;
if(isLittleEndian){
    val = 0x80d7ffff;
}
var i = 0;
while(i < data.length) {
    data[i++] = val; 
}
```

**A look at performance**

In the time it takes to write one value using (View) `view.Uint32(i,val);` you can write  33 values using (Direct) `data[i] = val;`

Stats from Firefox.

For constant cycle time test.

- Direct writes * 10,000 per cycle : 23222 97.07% 100%.
- View writes * 10,000 per cycle: 702 : 2.93% 3.02%

<sup>First % is percent of total. Second % is percent of fastest (Direct)</sup>

For performance time per 10,000 writes (time in 1/1,000,000 seconds)

- Direct 1701 cycles * 10000 writes. Mean : 43.063 (1e-6 sec). Variance : 0.210
- View 1701 cycles * 10000 writes. Mean : 1424.832 (1e-6 sec). Variance : 379.441

Note the high variance value for View this is due to Javascript optimisation. Doing short bursts of writes via View can be significantly slower.

For performance time per 10,000 writes (time in 1/1,000,000 seconds) allowing variance to stabilize.

- Direct 31636 cycles * 10000 writes. Mean : 29.981 (1e-6 sec). Variance : 0.005
- View 31802 cycles * 10000 writes. Mean : 982.195 (1e-6 sec). Variance : 0.154

---

### **More tests**

As requested in comments some more tests. A test unit is a call to one of the test functions. Thus in the following tests 10000 32Bit writes per test unit.

**Compare 8Bit writes to 32Bit writes**

functions tested

```
  testFunctions = [{
          func:function(){
              for(i = 0; i < 40000; i ++){
                  data[i++] = 0xFF;
                  data[i++] = 0xFF;
                  data[i++] = 0xd7;
                  data[i] = 0x80;
              }},
          name:"8Bit",
      },{
          func:function(){
              for(i = 0; i < 10000; i ++){
                  view2[i] = 0x80d7ffff;
             }},
          name:"32Bit",
      }
  ];
```

Common context

```
var i
var i,arr;
var data = new Uint8ClampedArray(100000);
var view2 = new Uint32Array(data.buffer);
```

Test results raw dump.

```
Test complete Results.
Function name, Calls per sec, % cycle time, % of best time
32Bit : 33743 : 76.84% 100%.
8Bit : 10170 : 23.16% 30.14%

Total cycles : 1000
Stable cycles : 899 Total.
Tests per cycle : 660
Testing cycles stable for : 800 of 800 cycles 100.00%
Max test variance 0.000%
Test results are good.

List of all test function results.
Mean times in micro secs 1/1,000,000 times mark with ms in milliseconds 1/1,000
# calls, total time, mean time
--------------------
Test function : 8Bit
62264 tests 6122.825ms Mean : 98
61942 tests 6088.945ms Mean : 98
62283 tests 6124.810ms Mean : 98
62233 tests 6121.010ms Mean : 98
Variance : 0.000micro sec. normalised : 0.000%
Ran : 248722 over 24457.590ms Mean : 98.333micro sec
--------------------
Test function : 32Bit
62084 tests 1839.180ms Mean : 30
61738 tests 1829.285ms Mean : 30
62282 tests 1846.225ms Mean : 30
62390 tests 1849.650ms Mean : 30
Variance : 0.000micro sec. normalised : 0.000%
Ran : 248494 over 7364.340ms Mean : 29.636micro sec
Total number of tests run : 497216
```

**The View and Direct write**

Detailed view of a test run described at the beginning of this answer.

Functions and shared context

```
 sharedFunction = function(){ 
    var i;
    var data = new Uint8ClampedArray(100000);
    var view1 = new DataView(data.buffer);
    var view2 = new Uint32Array(data.buffer);
 }
  testFunctions = [{
          func:function(){
              for(i = 0; i < 10000; i ++){
                  view1.setUint32(i, 0x80d7ffff); 
              }            
          },
          name:"View",
      },{
          func:function(){
              for(i = 0; i < 10000; i ++){
                  view2[i] = 0x80d7ffff;
             }},
          name:"Direct",
      }
  ];
```

Results

```
Test complete Results.
Calls per sec, % cycle time, % of best time
Direct : 35766 : 97.07% 100%.
View : 1080 : 2.93% 3.02%

Total cycles : 1000
Stable cycles : 899 Total.
Tests per cycle : 73
Testing cycles stable for : 800 of 800 cycles 100.00%
Max test variance 5.231%
Test results are good.

Mean times in micro secs 1/1,000,000 times mark with ms in milliseconds 1/1,000
# calls, total time, mean time
--------------------
Test function : View
8583 tests 7850.680ms Mean : 915
8454 tests 7830.950ms Mean : 926
8201 tests 7639.375ms Mean : 932
8459 tests 7883.150ms Mean : 932
Variance : 48.445micro sec. normalised : 5.231%
Ran : 33697 over 31204.155ms Mean : 926.022micro sec
--------------------
Test function : Direct
8434 tests 235.295ms Mean : 28
8347 tests 234.190ms Mean : 28
8451 tests 237.045ms Mean : 28
8260 tests 229.900ms Mean : 28
Variance : 0.009micro sec. normalised : 0.033%
Ran : 33492 over 936.430ms Mean : 27.960micro sec
Total number of tests run : 67189
```

> **Note** Each test function is run as 4 separate functions. A stable test is when all 4 current cycle test times match the previous test cycle times. Javascript optimization will cause times to vary and as there is no way to know for sure when optimisation is happening the testing code waits till all test functions return a stable time at least 100 cycles. Further cycle time instability will be shown in the variance values.
>
> Tests per cycle is an average (not noted in results)
>
> All test functions are run in random order via `testFunction[ Math.floor(Math.random() * testFunctionCount * testsPerFunction) ]();`
>
> Timing is via `performance.now();` and measures only the inner content of the test functions.

Comment: Thanks for that test, I wasn't curious enough to do it myself but glad to see it. Since you're at it, could you also check for multiple colors and even against the native Uint8ClampedArray iteration ?

Comment: @Kaiido I have added more detailed time info. Using different values (colours) to write will only bring the test result times closer together due to the common overhead of calculating a value to write. These tests are only good for discrete unique JS functionality comparisons, adding common functionality will make it hard to see where the difference is as it is unknown how optimisation will affect the combinations of code.

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I interpret it correctly it shows that DataView version becomes even slower than 8bitArray iteration. That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: @Kaiido That is correct. The write time for 8Bit and 32Bit are the same so 4 8bit writes is very close to the single 32bit write *4 with the 3 additional `i++` adding a little to the overall time for the 8Bit writes.

Comment: Impresive answer.

Comment: [This article from 2018](https://v8.dev/blog/dataview) explains that the poor performance of DataView was a bug that has since been fixed.